# Failed at the esbuild@0.15.8 postinstall script// This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above

Tags: javascript, npm, deployment, build

trying to do the

```
npm install
```

for the client folder in this project: https://github.com/alchemyplatform/ecdsa-node

Same problem occurs anyway:
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! esbuild@0.15.8 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the esbuild@0.15.8 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\thepe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2023-02-21T12_12_51_987Z-debug.log

====================================
I tried already

1. Delete your package-lock.json file and node_modules folder. Then do npm cache clean
2. npm cache clean --force
3. do npm install